# Honey moisture and increase in temperature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, bond

I've been interested quite lately on how moisture would be affected as the temperature increases. My experiment methodology is that I will be manipulating temperatures of the honey between 20,40,60,80 degrees celsius and I will be using a refractometer to measure moisture in brix. Will there be a slight change in the reading of the refractometer?

Comment: If you see a change depends greatly on the quality of your refractometer. // Does the refractometer itself have the ability to vary temperature of the cell? Hot honey will cool down if applied to a cold cell.

Comment: In fact, I am using the small refractometer with a trap door on the top(as soon as you search refractometer on google you will see it). If it is good for varying temperatures then how can we avoid the uncertainty of the cooling down of honey inside the cell?

Comment: If you measure it at different than nominal temperature, you would not know, if the refraction index change is due different water content, or due different temperature.

Comment: Normally temperature affects moisture therefore there is a change in refractive index. Do you have any other idea for the reason why could there be a change in refractive index other than moisture?

Comment: It was mentioned several times. n=f(T). Moisture=f(T) only indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you would cool it back before measurement, otherwise it would be measuring of temperature dependency of honey refraction index.

There would be change, it is the way how bees evaporate the excessive water to make honey stable. Obviously, it would be function of both temperature and time. As honey is very viscous, loosing water would be very slow in bulk volume and also place dependent, approximately following [the 2nd Fick's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion), unless being mixed.

But $60$ or $\pu{80 ^\circ C}$ is ridiculous, as it would not be honey any more, but just thick solution of fructose and glukose + some minor components. If honey is heated to dissolve crystallized sugars, it is recommended not to heat it more than $\pu{40 ^\circ C}$.